# How to make c++ function write on the last line of the output file each time it is called

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

The question is how to make ouput file have `1` on the 1st line, `2` on the 2nd etc. because the program as it is rewrites the file everytime the loop is executed and you are left only with `9` in the output file.

```
   #include <fstream>
   using namespace std;

   void function (int i)
   { 
       ofstream output("result.out");
       output << i << endl;
       output.close();
   }

   int main()
   {
       for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
       {
           function(i);
       }
       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Don't open and close it every time, or open it with [`app`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) flag.

Comment: I've never really called `output.close();` `ofstream` objects follow RAII and it closes automaticlly at the end of the function call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass `std::ios::app` as the second argument to `std::ofstream` constructor. I.e.

```
std::ofstream output("result.out", std::ios::app);
```

Comment: No need to or against `out`, it will do it for you.

Comment: @BoBTFish, yeah, I wasn't sure about that, I'm searching for standard's reference...

Comment: @BoBTFish, you're right, it's [ofstream.cons]/2: Constructs an object [...],
then calls rdbuf()->open(s, mode|ios_base::out).

Comment: I just checked http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream . Didn't feel the need to go to The Standard for this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it your way:

```
void function (int i)
{
    ofstream output("result.out", std::ios::app);
    output << i << endl;
    output.close();
}

int main()
{
    for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
    {
        function(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Adding **ios::app** will not erase the contents of the file but will append text to it. It has a drawback - if you will want to call the loop again old data is still there.

But I would suggest moving the the **for()** loop into the function.

```
void function (int i)
{
    ofstream output("result.out");
    for(int j = 1, j < i; j++              
        output << j << endl;                
    output.close();
}

int main()
{
    function(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Result is the same, you avoid opening and closing the file repeatedly and you can still use it as a function.